# How to massage inputs into Keras framework?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am new to keras and despite reading the documentation and the `examples` folder in keras, I'm still struggling with how to fit everything together.

In particular, I want to start with a simple task: I have a sequence of tokens, where each token has exactly one label. I have a lot training data like this - practically infinite, as I can generate more `(token, label)` training pairs as needed.

I want to build a network to predict labels given tokens. The number of tokens must always be the same as the number of labels (one token = one label).

And I want this to be **based on all surrounding tokens**, say within the same line or sentence or window -- not just on the preceding tokens.

**How far I got on my own:**

- created the training numpy vectors, where I converted each sentence into a token-vector and label-vector (of same length), using a token-to-int and label-to-int mappings
- wrote a model using `categorical_crossentropy` and one LSTM layer, based on https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py.

**Now struggling with:**

1. All the `input_dim` and `input_shape` parameters... since each sentence has a different length (different number of tokens and labels in it), what should I put as `input_dim` for the input layer?
2. How to tell the network to use the **entire token sentence** for prediction, not just one token? How to predict a whole sequence of labels given a sequence of tokens, rather than just label based on previous tokens?
3. Does splitting the text into sentences or windows make any sense? Or can I just pass a vector for the entire text as a single sequence? What is a "sequence"?
4. What are "time slices" and "time steps"? The documentation keeps mentioning that and I have no idea how that relates to my problem. What is "time" in keras?

Basically I have trouble connecting the concepts from the documentation like "time" or "sequence" to my problem. Issues like [Keras#40](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/40) didn't make me any wiser.

Pointing to relevant examples on the web or code samples would be much appreciated. Not looking for academic articles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have sequences of different length you can either pad them or use a stateful RNN implementation in which the activations are saved between batches. The former is the easiest and most used.
2. If you want to use future information when using RNNs you want to use a bidirectional model where you concatenate two RNN's moving in opposite directions. RNN will use a representation of all previous information when e.g. predicting.
3. If you have very long sentences it might be useful to sample a random sub-sequence and train on that. Fx 100 characters. This also helps with overfitting.
4. Time steps are your tokens. A sentence is a sequence of characters/tokens.

I've written an example of how I understand your problem but it's not tested so it might not run. Instead of using integers to represent your data I suggest one-hot encoding if it is possible and then use `binary_crossentropy` instead of `mse`.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

# Make sure all sequences are of same length
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=maxlen)

# The input shape is your sequence length and your token embedding size (which is 1)
inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen, 1))

# Build a bidirectional RNN
lstm_forward = LSTM(128)(inputs)
lstm_backward = LSTM(128, go_backwards=True)(inputs)
bidirectional_lstm = merge([lstm_forward, lstm_backward], mode='concat', concat_axis=2)

# Output each timestep into a fully connected layer with linear 
# output to map to an integer
sequence_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(bidirectional_lstm)
# Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid') if you want to classify

model = Model(inputs, sequence_output)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```